# How to access the website publicly? Web Server 2016 | IIS

Tags: windows, iis, webserver, portforwarding

I am trying to access the application in my local that i have hosted in windows webserver 16 but I am unable to access it.

I have Already tried 
 CP -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced settings -> Inbound Rules -> New Rule... Select port, TCP and also tried the outbound

In IIS I have hosted the application using prefix of IP address.

Comment: Could you add some details? for example, what's your application binding or other details

Comment: Ya Can you please say what are the other details along with application Binding is required? Am trying this for the first time so dont have much knowlwdge
Type is HTTP
port is 2100
Host name is blank

Comment: Here Are the binding Details
Type is HTTP
port is 2100
Host name is blank
IP Address is having its Value
Binding Information is also Blank

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef You didn't yet test the internal client scenario, so jumping to external client is too quick.

Comment: I don't have internal clients. as I am just trying in AWS RDC.